# In VHDL, flushing output buffer before calling stop. Or report a message then stop stimulator instead of finish simulator

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

In VHDL is there a way to flush the output buffer before calling stop?  (usually, they want you to fiddle around with simulator invocation flags to do this... I would prefer a code solution to this problem)

in other words, I want to $stop, not $finish, but to flush the output buffer before calling stop;

example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;
use std.env.stop;

entity testit is
   port(
      clk : in std_logic
   );
end entity;

architecture rtl of testit is
begin

    process(clk) 
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        report "message 1" & LF;
        --<- insert Command to wait until "message 1" is flushed to console
        stop;
    end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
end process;
```

The problem i get is that the report "message 1" doesn't get output to the simulation screen before the stop is issued in the VHDL simulation ... which makes my simulation log worthless...  (I'm using the simulator built into vivado)

I realize, i could put the keywords  "severity fatal" on the end of the report statement... but, the reason I can't do this  is because it kills my simulation waveform in vivado.  Thus, I need to make "report" nonfatal, and put stop keyword after it.  however, this leads to other problems....

Does anybody know of a different way to issue a simulator stop from the testbench code and to print a message?  such that the waveform windows remains open and the simulator doesn't exit.

Comment: VHDL has no output buffer to flush for report statements. If there is one, its a tool issue. If the message isnt reporting appearing in the log, then its likely a tool defect. The message will be reported with severity `NOTE`  Your code also contains an error due to the extra `end process` after the `end architecture;` .

Comment: There is also no begin for the process. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: -2008 which implements std.env.stop also provides an implicit FLUSH function for each file type declaration that can be called with a file object of that type. There is no guarantee that report uses the predefined OUTPUT file in package STANDARD.  You could certainly try to FLUSH(OUTPUT), assuming Vivado simulator implements FLUSH and the host OS file descriptor for OUTPUT is used by report statements. It wouldn't otherwise be inimical in -2008 compliant code for other implementations.

Comment: Tricky, I didn't compile this code... i'm just giving an example of the problem i'm having with vivado VHDL simulator.  Thanks user1155120... that's good information..

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this works in VHDL-2008 to print a message, flush the output buffer, and $stop the simulator:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;
use std.env.stop;

entity test_stop is
    port(
        clk :in  std_logic
    );
end entity;


architecture sim of sim_amm_m is

    procedure print(s: in string) is
        variable L :line;  
    begin
        write(L, string'(s & LF));
        writeline(output, L);
        flush(output);
    end procedure;
    
begin

    process(clk)
    begin    
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then      
            print("STOP CONDITIION");    
            stop; 
        end if;
    end process;
                             
end architecture;
```

Also, you can get it to $finish the simulation, but that also closes the waveform viewer when running an interactive simulation:

```
   print("FINISH CONDITIION");    
   finish;
```